# DataLayer push display field validation

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Currently i have field validation working as expected using **DataAnnotations** when user click **Create Account** button

So what i need to do next is to pass fields that failed on User click **Create Account** button to `Validation Fields` under **validate** function below.

So if any fields (Username, Firstname) failed validation (i.e Username or FirstName) then Validations function will replace `Validation Fields` with any failed field. For example if validation failed for username. so the 'Validation fields': username. If both  field failed then then 'Validation fields': Username, Password.

Account.cs

```
[Required("Username is required")]
[StringLength(9, ErrorMessage="Must be under 9 characters")]
public string Username {get; set;}

[Required("Firstname is required")]
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage="Must be under 20 characters")]
public string Firstname {get; set;}
```

Account.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form-main" }))

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "styled" })

             <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter here" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "styled" })

                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter here" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "styled" })

                </div>
            <button id="btnCreateAccount" type="submit" onclick="onCreateAccount()">Create Account</button>
        }



@section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate() {
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                window.dataLayer.push({
                    'event': 'Submit',
                    'Status': 'Fail',
                    'Label': 'Account Register form',
                    'Validation Fields': 'failed field validation' 
                });
            }

        function onCreateAccount()
        {
            Validate()
        }
        </script>   

}
```

So how can achieve the scenario above where i can get field(s) that are fail validation then pass it to **'Validation Field'** in **Validate** function?

Comment: What is the question/problem? - seems like you know what you want to do, what are you stuck at?

Comment: @Matus, I have update my questions